# par(mfrow=c(1,2)) not displaying side-by-side densityplots

Tags: r

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(1:12, log = "y")
plot(1:2, xaxs = "i")
```

[image]

However, when I try to do a side-by-side densityplot the plots get output seperately:

```
# load the stud.recs dataset
library(UsingR)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
densityplot(stud.recs$sat.v)
densityplot(stud.recs$sat.m)
```

Why is `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` not working for the density plots?

Comment: Note: `densityplot` is not documented in `UsingR` but does exist.  There is also `DensityPlot` but it uses base graphics.  `densityplot` is also not in the namespace so I'm not sure how it is exposed.  Separate issue from this question of course.

Comment: OK. Got it, red-herring as they say.  `UsingR` has nothing to do with this question.  `densityplot` belongs to `lattice`.

Comment: upvoted your first comment for pointing me to `DensityPlot` which worked as I expected `densityplot` to work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`densityplot` produces lattice plots (which are different to base plots).

So in order to have them side by side you need to do:

```
library(UsingR)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
a <- densityplot(stud.recs$sat.v)
b <- densityplot(stud.recs$sat.m)

#this is the print.lattice method below
# ?print.trellis for help
print(a, position = c(0, 0, 0.5, 1), more = TRUE)
print(b, position = c(0.5, 0, 1, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: This suggested solution does not work for me.